# Worklight Studio - error http 405 when connecting to mobile URL provided by Console

Tags: web-applications, mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I've built and deployed with success a web app with android/mobile connecting to server locally.

it was ok with 5.0.5 (android preview, common preview, webapp preview and so on). I've upgraded to 5.0.6.

now the URL given by the Console ("Get URL of Mobile Web App") is not working and throw me a http error 405 "Get method not supported".

Is there an issue with 5.0.6 (studio) or i'm missing new settings?
thanx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to delete the yourEclipseWorkspace\WorklightServerHome folder before building your upgraded project. There have been schema changes and it MAY interrupt here as well.

From my testing in a new application in 5.0.6 with the Mobile Web environment, there are no such errors.

Comment: i've already deleted the worklightServerHome folder due to other bugs. It did not solve my issues with existing app. i'm gonna try with other apps and tell you.