# IBM Worklight - Error 405 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I've encountered a problem during development.

When the adapter is tested from within Eclipse ("Invoke Worklight procedure"), it does its job perfectly.

On the contrary, when the adapter is called from the app, it doesn't work. I receive the following error:

> Error 405 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

I've noticed a strange thing. When the adapter is called from the test procedure the URL seems correct (`/apps/services/api/...`) In the other case, Worklight puts a `worklight` prefix (`/worklight/apps/services/api/...`) when it makes the call. Hence the URL cannot be reached.

Here [Worklight Studio - error http 405 when connecting to mobile URL provided by Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617204/worklight-studio-error-http-405-when-connecting-to-mobile-url-provided-by-cons) I found a partial solution but it does not work.

**Additional info**

WL version is 5.0.6.
Application server is Tomcat 7.

Comment: Not enough information. Edit the question with: 1) Worklight version. 2) Used application server. It sounds like you deploy the app to an external server

Comment: @IdanAdar Thanks. I'll edit asap.

Comment: @IdanAdar I've found the problem. See my answer. Anyway I've added additional info. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my experiments I found the problem.

Each worklight project has an `application-descriptor.xml`. Within it there is a tag that indicates the WL server root URL.

Since I've taken the project from another source, I've simply noticed that it was configured as

```
<worklightServerRootURL>http://sampleDomain/worklight</worklightServerRootURL>
```

where `sampleDomain` is only a placeholder for the real one.

Now it is configured like

```
<worklightServerRootURL>http://${local.IPAddress}:8080</worklightServerRootURL>
```

to perform internal local tests.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @IdanAdar I need to wait 2 days. ;)

Comment: @flexaddicated, BTW, you will still need to add the context root to the worklightServerRootURL value if you intend on moving from development to test/produdction.

Comment: @IdanAdar Thanks. Could you explain better? I cannot understand. Thanks.

Comment: @IdanAdar Are you saying that I need to use the first config when going in production?

Comment: When you use an application server, be it WAS or Liberty or Tomcat, it requires a context root (the "/worklight") for the project you deploy. So when moving forward, be sure you add the context root to both application-descriptor.xml as well as in worklight.properties prior to deploying the project's .war file in the application server.

Comment: It doesn't have to be "/worklight", of course. That's up to you.

Comment: @IdanAdar Thanks. Where can I find it on docs? I've seen you are working for IBM... ;)

Comment: Download the Getting Started modules for 5.0.6. Probably mentioned there: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/previous-versions.html You should also search through the Information Center: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp

Comment: @IdanAdar Thank you very much for your availability. Have a nice day. I will post soon. ;)

Comment: Sure. If you have a **technical** question open a new question, otherwise this question has been answered (as mentioned above).